# Swift Choosing Specific Value by Condition

Tags: swift, dictionary, inheritance

I am applying a simple inheritance project using Swift. However, after completing my code, getting this error all the time.This project creates vehicle class and has 2 child classes as Car and Bicycle.
Car has speed depending on its chosen gear. 
So I implement a gearBox dictionary which has gear as key and speed as value.

I am not sure if I could assign speed value by controlling its gear in my Car class.

Any help would be appreciated.

> **MY ERROR**
>   Playground execution failed: error: psionix.playground:19:34: error: use of 'self' in property access 'speed' before super.init initializes self
>           super.init(speedVehicle: speed)
>                                    ^

**MY CODE**

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class Vehicle{

    var speed : Double


    init(speedVehicle:Double){
        speed = speedVehicle
    }

    func printDescription(){
        print("Vehicle has \(speed) km/h speed by default.")
    }
}

class Car : Vehicle{

    var speedCar :Double
    let gearBox : [Int : Double] = [1:10.5, 2:23.3, 3:33.4, 4:45.0, 5:51.2]

    init(){
        super.init(speedVehicle: speed)
    }

    func calculateTravelTime(distance:Double, gearCar:Int)->Double{
        var travelTime : Double

        travelTime = distance/speedCar

        for (gear, speed) in gearBox{
            if(gear == gearCar){

                speedCar = speed
            }

        }
        return travelTime
    }


    override func printDescription() {
        print("My Car has \(gearBox.count) gears and has \(speedCar) km/h speed.")
    }


}

class Bicycle : Vehicle{

    var hasBasket : Bool
    var distance : Double  // in km
    var speedBicycle : Double

    init(hasBasket: Bool){
        super.init(speedVehicle: speed)
        self.hasBasket = hasBasket
    }

     func calculateTravelTime(speed:Double)->Double{
        let time = (distance/speed)
        print("Bicycle travel time is: \(time)")
        return time
    }



    override func printDescription() {
        if(hasBasket == true){
            print("My Bicycle has \(speedBicycle) km/h speed and its has a basket.")
        }
        else{
            print("My Bicycle has \(speedBicycle) km/h speed and its has no basket.")
        }
    }
}

let myVehicle = Vehicle(speedVehicle:3.0)
myVehicle.printDescription()

let myCar = Car()
print("My car travel time is  \(myCar.calculateTravelTime(distance: 100.0, gearCar:3)) hours.")
myCar.printDescription()

let myBicycle = Bicycle(hasBasket:true)
print("My bicycle travel time is \(myBicycle.calculateTravelTime(speed: 10)) hours.")
myBicycle.printDescription()
```

Comment: thanks for editing @Alladinian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to call the initializer of your superclass without actually providing all necessary values as input arguments to `super.init(speed:)`. You need to change your init methods to provide a speed value.

```
class Car : Vehicle{
    ...

    init(speed: Double){
        super.init(speedVehicle: speed)
    }
}

class Bicycle : Vehicle{
    ...
    init(speed: Double,hasBasket: Bool){
        super.init(speedVehicle: speed)
        self.hasBasket = hasBasket
    }
}
```

And do the same for all your `Vehicle` subclasses. Moreover, the `speedCar` property is not needed, since `Car` already has a `speed` property inherited from `Vehicle`, same for `speedBicycle` in `Bicycle`.

If you want all your subclass instances to have the same speed, just set up a default value in the init method like so:

```
class Car : Vehicle{
    ...

    init(){
        let carSpeed = 50.0
        super.init(speedVehicle: carSpeed)
        //you could even do super.init(speedVehicle: 50), I just used a variable for clarity
    }
}
```

Moreover, you should never iterate through a dictionary to find a certain key, you can safely access values using subscripting. If the key doesn't exist, the value will simply be `nil`.

```
func calculateTravelTime(distance:Double, gearCar:Int)->Double{
    if let currentSpeed = gearBox[gear] {
        speedCar = currentSpeed
    }
    return distance/speedCar
}
```

Comment: but I want to assign speedCar to speed value depending on gear number. So, should I still not add speedCar property?

Comment: If `speedCar` represents a completely different thing than the vehicle's speed, then you can keep it, but than I suggest changing it's name. However, your current code doesn't show any use of the `speedCar` variable, so without seeing your logic it's hard to give an exact answer.

Comment: `speedCar` is Car instance's speed variable. And I want to choose speed value depending on gear number from my `gearBox` dictionary by iterating, as you can see in the code.

Comment: In that case, I would rather name `speedCar` to `currentSpeed`, since as I understand, that's what it is actually representing. Moreover, check my updated answer, you should never iterate through a dictionary to look for a certain key-value pair, I've included a more optimal `calculateTravelTime` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are init your Bicycle and Car, before you set it speed. Add speed before you called super.init method
Edit this

```
   init(hasBasket: Bool){
    speedBicycle = 0
    super.init(speedVehicle: speedBicycle)
    self.hasBasket = hasBasket
}
```

And This

```
 init(){
    speedCar = 0
    super.init(speedVehicle: speedCar)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense that any Vehicle has an initial speed of either a user desired value, or 0 by default. Same happens with a Car, and since a Car is a Vehicle, you don't need two different speeds.

This would be my refined approach:

```
import Foundation

class Vehicle: CustomStringConvertible {

    var speedInKmH: Double

    init(speedInKmH: Double = 0) {
        self.speedInKmH = speedInKmH
    }

    var description: String {
        return "Vehicle has \(speedInKmH) km/h speed by default."
    }
}

struct GearBox {
    var gear: Int
    var speedInKmH: Double
}

class Car: Vehicle {

    let gearBox: [GearBox] = [GearBox(gear: 1, speedInKmH: 10.5), GearBox(gear: 3, speedInKmH: 33.4), GearBox(gear: 5, speedInKmH: 51.2),
                        GearBox(gear: 2, speedInKmH: 23.3), GearBox(gear: 4, speedInKmH: 45.0)]

    func travelTimeInHoursWith(distanceInKm: Double, gear: Int) -> Double {

        if let matchedGearBox = gearBox.filter({ $0.gear == gear }).first {
            self.speedInKmH = matchedGearBox.speedInKmH
        }

        return distanceInKm / speedInKmH
    }

    override var description: String {
        return "My Car has \(self.gearBox.count) gears and has \(self.speedInKmH) km/h speed."
    }
}

let toyota = Car()
print(toyota.travelTimeInHoursWith(distanceInKm: 22, gear: 4))
print(toyota)
```

I did some improvements to make it clear, you can take my code as example and modify your other implemented class/classes